# How to send email verification to user after registration PHP

Tags: php, email

I want to send email verifcation link to user after registration in php. I'm getting the following error;

> Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. the user data is actually inserting into database.

below is my email verification code;

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config/constants.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
  ->setUsername(EMAIL)
  ->setPassword(PASSWORD);

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);


function sendVerificationEmail($email, $token){

    global $mailer;

    $body = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Verify email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p> Thank you for registrating on our website. Please click on the link below to verify your email</p>
            <a href="http://localhost/medxpress-ng/index.php?token= '. $token. '"> Verify your email address</a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>';

    // Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Verify your email address'))
  ->setFrom(EMAIL)
  ->setTo($email)
  ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

}
?>
```

Comment: Check the values of `EMAIL` on the line `->setFrom(EMAIL)` and `$email` on the line `->setTo($email)`. My guess is at least one of them is empty. More likely the `EMAIL` (capitalized) because it looks like you're incorrectly accessing a constant (example of correctly accessing it: `self::EMAIL`)... Edit: Also check the values passed to `->setUsername(EMAIL)` and `->setPassword(PASSWORD)` because this snippet could fail first (I don't know which runs first without the context).

Comment: i checked the values and edited but not working still. today am getting this error; Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Comment: That means the original issue was really the empty values being passed. And the second error "Username and Password not accepted" speaks for itself. You're passing incorrect (maybe still empty) credentials.